# appropriate regex to select text within a string?

Tags: regex, matlab

Let's say I have these strings:

```
row - 1: First_s - end

row - 2: Second_s - end

...

row - 400: string_400 - end
```

I'd like to use the matlab function `regexp` to select any non-white character that is between `:` and `- end`. So in my example it would select `First_s Second_s string_400`, etc. What would an appropriate regex look like?

Comment: Something like this @":(.+?)- end";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a strict lookbehind and lookahead: `(?<=: ).+?(?= - end)`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of lookaheads and lookbehinds, you match the strings that lead and trail the tokens:

```
>> Cs = regexp(strings,':\ (.*)\ - end','tokens');
>> Cs{1}{1}
ans = 
    'First_s'
>> Cs{2}{1}
ans = 
    'Second_s'
>> Cs{3}{1}
ans = 
    'string_400'
```

Answer (score 1):

Uses [`regexprep`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) to replace unwanted parts by nothing:

```
strings = {
'row - 1: First_s - end';
'row - 2: Second_s - end';
'row - 400: string_400 - end'}; %// example data. Assumed to be a cell array

strings = regexprep(strings,'.*:','') %// remove start
strings = regexprep(strings,'- end$','') %// remove end
strings = regexprep(strings,'\s','') %// remove spaces
```

The result in this example is:

```
strings = 

    'First_s'
    'Second_s'
    'string_400'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the regex that works with ruby: `row\s\-\s[\d]+\:\s(.*)\s-\send` which would probably work with matlab as well.

You can see how this example works here: http://rubular.com/r/FuPwNcBy1I